# HTML checkbox array not correctly passed to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I've got an array of checkboxes I need to display to the user the options they select to provide a total price for those options. The issue is that when I run the code I don't get any value in the array and I'm not sure why because I've correctly referenced the checkboxes. I've tried fixing the number of iterations in the for loop and renaming variables but I cant seem to get it to work.

```js
var checkbox_list = document.forms[0];
var txt = "";
var checkedValue = null;
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName("checkboxb");

for (var i = 0; inputElements[i]; i++) {
    if (inputElements[i].checked) {

        txt +=  checkbox_list[i].value + ", ";
        alert(txt);

        break;
    }
}
document.getElementById("quote").innerText = txt + "";
```

```html
<div id="checkboxes">
    <label for="one"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxb" 
     name="options1"/>First checkbox</label>

    <label for="two"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxb" 
     name="options2"/>Second checkbox</label>

    <label for="three"><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxb" 
     name="options3"/>Third checkbox</label>
</div>
```

Comment: My guess is that the break command may be immediately exiting the for loop.

Comment: Oh and try to set the range in the loop as i < inputElements.length

Comment: Wow, that was actually it. I suppose I should just call it a night since I missed that. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want an ES6 approach.

```js
// This line just stores the inputs
const inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName("checkboxb");

// This replaces your for-loop. It iterates through the inputs and if they are checked,
// add the current value to an accumulated value
const calculate = _ => [...inputElements].reduce((a, c) => c.checked ? (a + ", " + c.value) : a, "").substr(2);

// This just performs the calculation whenever checkbox change, and display that result
[...inputElements].forEach(x => x.addEventListener("change", _ => quote.innerText = calculate()));
```

```html
<div id="checkboxes">
    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxb" 
     name="options1" value="one"/>First checkbox</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxb" 
     name="options2" value="two"/>Second checkbox</label>

    <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxb" 
     name="options3" value="three"/>Third checkbox</label>
</div>

<div id="quote"></div>
```